# Appium Ruby to test on android mobile real device web browser

Tags: android, ruby, appium

I am trying to configure Appium with Ruby to test on real device web browser. 
I was able to perform it using Appium selenium java, but as my functional testing is in ruby need to find a solution in Ruby

1. Do we have appium ruby solution to test on android real device webbrowser
2. Can some one help to find the setup guidelines for android, i tried a lot but was not able to find

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appium can handle webview, & does have a ruby client:

https://rubygems.org/gems/appium_lib/versions/7.0.0

Here's a link to the android setup:

http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#setup-(android)

Comment: No problem, glad to help out.